# React Native, in a text string, change color of words having # or @ in start just like twitter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a text string some of words are having # or @ as prefix (in start of words, just as #example or @example) i want to change such words into blue color . React Native

Comment: please share your code

Comment: just make them into anchor tags.

Comment: const CustomText = (props) => {
    const text = props.text.split(' ');
    return <Text>{text.map(text => {
      if (text.startsWith('@') || text.startsWith('#')) {
        return <Text style={{ color: 'blue' }}>{text} </Text>;
      }
      return `${text} `;
    })}</Text>;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
       <CustomText text="this is a @sample #text"/>
    </View>
  );
}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a custom component like below.

```
const CustomText = (props) => {
    const text = props.text.split(' ');
    return <Text>{text.map(text => {
      if (text.startsWith('@') || text.startsWith('#')) {
        return <Text style={{ color: 'blue' }}>{text} </Text>;
      }
      return `${text} `;
    })}</Text>;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
       <CustomText text="this is a @sample #text"/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

You can check the working snack
https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/demo2

Comment: Thanks code is quite fine, how about compiler, would this loop be feasible to run?
One more thing, for loop or map? what is most suitable in the favor of compiler?

Comment: If you are going to have longer string then you will have to think about performance. Loop or map is hard question to answer please refer https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/map-vs-for-loop-2b4ce659fb03

Comment: Thanks @guruparan this works for me. I'm upvoting the answer to make public reach higher. Thanks once again.

Comment: @SobanArshad you are welcome :), if it helps you can mark it as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution for this problem:

```
const changeColorInText = useMemo(() => {
        const textWithQuote = text.split("'")[1];
        const textParsed: string[] = text.split(textWithQuote);
        return (
            <>
                <Text>{textParsed[0]}</Text>
                <Text
                    style={{
                        color: 'red',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                    }}>
                    {textWithQuote}
                </Text>
                <Text>{textParsed[1]}</Text>
            </>
        );
    }, [text]);
```

I think will help for maybe different scenarios